# MIME TYPE error using CDN/Javascript module in flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

In my static folder in a Flask app, i have this javascript file, which i provided the code for.
It contains a link to a cdn.

In my base.html i try to import it like this

```
<script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/chart.js') }}"></script>
```

But i get this error:

*Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.*

I have to make the js file into a module otherwise i get :

*chart.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module*

what would be the correct way of using the cdn in a flask enviroment?

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Flaskr</title>¨

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='list.css') }}" />

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}" defer></script>

<script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/chart.js') }}"></script>
<nav>
  <h1>Flaskr</h1>
  <ul>
    {% if g.user %}
    <li><span>{{ g.user['username'] }}</span></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Log Out</a> {% else %}</li>

    <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.register') }}">Register</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Log In</a>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section class="content">
  <header>{% block header %}{% endblock %}</header>
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
  <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %} {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</section>
```

THE JS MODULE:

```
import lightweightCharts from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightweight-charts@4.1.1/+esm";
const chart_div = document.querySelector(".chart");

const chart = lightweightCharts.createChart(chart_div, {
  width: 600,
  height: 300,
  layout: {
    background: {
      type: "solid",
      color: "#000000",
    },
    textColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)",
  },
  grid: {
    vertLines: {
      color: "rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)",
    },
    horzLines: {
      color: "rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)",
    },
  },
  crosshair: {
    mode: CrosshairMode.Normal,
  },
  rightPriceScale: {
    borderColor: "rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.8)",
  },
  timeScale: {
    timeVisible: true,
    // secondsVisible: false,
    borderColor: "rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.8)",
  },
});

var candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries({
  upColor: "rgba(255, 144, 0, 1)",
  downColor: "#000",
  borderDownColor: "rgba(255, 144, 0, 1)",
  borderUpColor: "rgba(155, 144, 0, 1)",
  wickDownColor: "rgba(55, 144, 0, 1)",
  wickUpColor: "rgba(255, 144, 0, 1)",
});

candleSeries.setData([
  { time: Date.parse("2019-04-11 09:43"), open: 107.2, high: 207.3, low: 207.1, close: 207.1 },
  { time: Date.parse("2019-04-11 12:43"), open: 407.2, high: 207.3, low: 207.1, close: 207.1 },
  { time: Date.parse("2019-04-11 13:43"), open: 307.2, high: 407.3, low: 207.1, close: 207.1 },
  { time: Date.parse("2019-04-11 14:43"), open: 107.2, high: 207.3, low: 207.1, close: 207.1 },
]);
```